# XSS scan with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, security, xss

I am trying to make XSS scanner using selenium. First I tried checking for XSS with the response until I realized that is a poor way to check. I started using Selenium because I thought it would be better at interacting with pages and able to detect the alert box popping up. I built a vulnerable website with a simple form and tested it, but it just fills the form without causing the alert to popup, here is code i used

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def check_xss(url, input_boxes):
    vulnerabilities = []
    
    payloads = [
        "<script>alert('XSS')</script>",
        "<img src='x' onerror='alert(\"XSS\")'>",
        "<svg/onload=alert('XSS')>",
        "<svg><script>alert('XSS')</script>",
        "'\"><script>alert('XSS')</script>",
        "';alert('XSS');//",
        "%3Cscript%3Ealert('XSS')%3C/script%3E"
    ]

   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    try:
        for input_box in input_boxes:
            if 'name' in input_box.attrs:
                print(f"Testing for XSS on input box : {input_box['name']}")
                for payload in payloads:
              
                    driver.get(url)
                    
               
                    input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, input_box['name'])
                    
                  
                    input_field.send_keys(payload)
                    
                 
                    input_field.submit()
                    
      
                    time.sleep(1)
                    
          
                    try:
                        alert = driver.switch_to.alert
                        vulnerabilities.append({
                            'type': 'XSS',
                            'input_param': input_box['name'],
                            'payload': payload,
                            'result': f'XSS Success with payload : {payload}'
                        })
                        print(f"XSS Success with payload : {payload}")
                        alert.accept()  # Close the alert dialog
                    except:
                        pass  # No alert dialog appeared, so continue testing

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

    if not vulnerabilities:
        print(f"No XSS vulnerability found for input box: {input_box['name']}")

    return vulnerabilities
```

With this it just fills the form and doesnt trigger the alert box, even though i know its XSS vulnernable and when maunually doing the attack the alert box appears.

How can I get this to actually check for XSS

I can't figure out how to make this work, ive tried increasing the timeout but it didnt do anything

Comment: You may need to set the unhandledPromptBehaviour as the default is dismiss and notify (it dismisses the prompt on the next action and throws an exception... that may happen when you go to use driver.switch_to...)  Ex: chrome_options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'ignore') See here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#unhandledpromptbehavior